# C - How do I attach ASCII-Code to char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, ascii

I have to make a char array out of many strings/ASCII-Code.
While adding strings works fine, adding ASCII-Code does not.

```
char line[50];
strcat(line, " "); // works
for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++) strcat(line, '196'); // supposed to add lines
for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++) strcat(line, 196);
```

Neither of these work. I always get this error message(had to translate it).

> Exception at 0x00E620E7 in the test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access Violation While Reading a Location 0x00313936.

What am I missing? Thanks for your help

Comment: As `line` is not initialized it contains "random" content. Concatenating anything to a random string can work or not. Even if you used a correct string to add via `strcat` you would run out of bounds as you add 60 times to a string which only occupies 50 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the ascii code, why not write it directly?

```
line[i] = 196;
```

Will this work?

Comment: because i dont always know what value i is. might get away with measuring the length of the witten string tho. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In C, String is written between double quotes.
Example `"abc"` is a string.

To `strcat()`, you are suppose to pass dst and str pointers which are pointing to a string.

In the line #2, you are correctly using `strcat()`. line is pointer to char array, and `" "` is pointer to a string literal.

But in line #3, `'196'` is not a string. If you want to write 196 to string, it should be `strcat(line, "196");`

Same goes for line #4.

Please note the following.

- In line #1, you are just declaring char array and not initializing it. So it can contain anything. So your strcat in line#2 can start from outside the array also if there is no '\0' character in the allocated array. So better initialize it - `char line[50] = ""`;
- Regarding line#2 and line#3: If you want continuous charaqcter-196, you can do one of the following - `for(..,i < MAX-1,..) line[i]=196; line[i+1]='\0';` OR `for(..,i < MAX-1,..)  strcat(line, "_"/* Assuming this is the character for 196*/);`

Comment: well but i want the char '196', which is a horizontal line, to be added to the char array, not the number 196. sorry if i wasnt clear enough

Comment: @2xWollert then write line[i] = 196; I But make sure that the last character of the string is always '\0'.

Comment: Nitpick: `" "` is **not** a pointer to a string literal; it is a string literal (type `char[2]`: array of 2 char) which, in many contexts, is converted to a pointer to the array's first element.

Answer (score 0):

`196` is a `char` (or an `int`), not a string, and it is not a valid parameter for `strcat` (which means 'string concatenation'). `'196'` is nothing valid at all and will not compile.

Strings are *sequences* of chars that end with a `'\0'`. If you want to append a single char, you have to either handle it manually (by directly assigning it, for example `line[i] = 196;`), or you have to use a _dummy helper string_with two chars, like: `char dummy[2]; dummy[0] = 196; dummy[1] = '\0';` and then `strcat(line,dummy);`